# Error: Type with name "Long" does not exists

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo, neo4j-apoc, grandstack

I am doing a code along project of GRAND stack real-estate-app "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WB--CkjKJMQ&list=PL9Hl4pk2FsvUjfSsxLolVToO5t1hwEIKK&index=2"

I have installed all the dependencies and configured the database `v3.5.18` and set the configurations in `.env` file.

After that I ran the `inferschema:write` script.

the schema.graphql file was updated with the following code

```
type Property {
   _id: Long!
   AddressL_1: String
   AddressLin: String
   Assessment: String
   COUNTYCD: Int!
   CareOfTaxp: String
   Certificat: String
   CityStateZ: String
   Continuous: Float!
   CountyAbbr: String!
   CountyName: String!
   DbaName: String
   FallowAcre: Float!
   FarmsiteAc: Float!
   ForestAcre: Float!
   GISAcres: Float!
   GrazingAcr: Float!
   IrrigatedA: Float!
   LegalDescr: String
   LevyDistri: String
   NonQualAcr: Float!
   OwnerAdd_1: String
   OwnerAdd_2: String
   OwnerAddre: String
   OwnerCity: String
   OwnerName: String
   OwnerState: String
   OwnerZipCo: String
   PropType: String
   PropertyID: Int!
   Range: String
   SHAPE_Area: Float!
   SHAPE_Leng: Float!
   Section: String
   Subdivisio: String
   TaxYear: Int!
   TotalAcres: Float!
   TotalBuild: Int!
   TotalLandV: Int!
   TotalValue: Int!
   Township: String
   WildHayAcr: Float!
   id: String!
}
```

Then when I run the server, it I gives me the following error

> C:\Users<path-to-folder>\practice-GRAND->STACK\realEstateApp\api\node_modules\graphql-compose\lib\TypeStorage.js:44

```
 throw new Error(`Type with name ${(0, _misc.inspect)(typeName)} does not exists`);
 Error: Type with name "Long" does not exists
```

Comment: graphQL [always] supported types: https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Scalars - you need a custom scalar defs

Answer (score 0):

add scalar Long to schema.graphql should solve the issue, but then another issue if you restrictly follow the youTube to use database v3.5.18

Driver is connected to the database that does not support multiple databases. Please upgrade to neo4j 4.0.0 or later in order to use this functionality

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).